# HardHat: Contracts supposedly deploying but not showing in MetaMask Activity

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to deploy 2 contracts to test and I copied the deploy script that I used on a different project (it worked fine there). It's immediately saying they deployed but I get nothing.

CMD.exe:

```
C:\Users\B\Desktop\PoolHH>npx hardhat run --network ropsten scripts/deploy.js
Deploying FLC...
FLC deployed to: ${FLCinstance.address}
Deploying TLWF...
TLWF deployed to: ${TLWFinstance.address}
```

deploy.js:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const ethers = hre.ethers;

async function main() {
  const flc = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("FLC");
  const FLCinstance = await flc.deploy;
  console.log('Deploying FLC...');
  
  await FLCinstance.deployed;
  console.log('FLC deployed to: ${FLCinstance.address}');
  

  const TLWF = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TimeLockedWalletFactory");
  const TLWFinstance = await TLWF.deploy;
  console.log('Deploying TLWF...');

  await TLWFinstance.deployed;
  console.log('TLWF deployed to: ${TLWFinstance.address}');
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Hardhat.config.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const { projectId, mnemonic } = require('./secrets.json');

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
require('hardhat-deploy');
require('hardhat-deploy-ethers');
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVKEY;

const privateKeyDev = "removed for this post";
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    ropsten: {
      url: "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/  removed this for the post ",
      accounts: {mnemonic: mnemonic},
      gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      skipDryRun: true,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      
      {
        version: "0.6.6",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
        
      },
    ],
  },
  //},
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
};
```

secrets.js:

```
{
    "mnemonic": " removed ",
    "projectId": " removed project id"
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution